# A nice random-cleaning-walk through a square

Tags: geometry, random, monte-carlo

Consider a square of side $L$. Create inside the square $N$ points randomly distributed. Starting from the center of the square (probably not important where you start) move straight to the closest point and erase it. Keep going with the same logic until the square is clean. What is the length $D$ of the polygonal chain you've covered? $$D = f(L,N)?$$ I've divided the square's area $A$ in $N$ equilateral triangles of area $a = A/N = L^2/N$. I've made this hypothesis: being $w$ the triangles' apothem and $d$ the length of the single step of the chain $d = 2 w$. Using the relation beetween the apothem and the area in an equilateral triangle I've expressed $d$ as a function of $L$ and $N$: $$d=2w=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3\sqrt{3}}}\frac{L}{\sqrt{N}}$$ So with the hypothesis $D = N d$ I've found a candidate for the relation I was looking for: $$D = N d = N \frac{2}{\sqrt{3\sqrt{3}}}\frac{L}{\sqrt{N}}$$ After some manupulation $$D = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3\sqrt{3}}} L \sqrt{N}\simeq 0.877 L \sqrt{N}$$
I've set up some Montecarlo simulations and the results seem consistant. What do you think about it? Could you spot any flaws in my reasoning? Or better, cold you find a way to prove it's right?

Comment: Don't you need the distribution of distances to the closest neighbour ?

Comment: I've just found the formula following the reasoning described... then the Montecarlo simulations were consistant... if there are no flaws probably everything necessary is there... but actually I don't know.

Comment: My simulation ($N=100$ ten thousand times) suggested something rather greater than your $0.877$  (an average of around $0.9118 \pm 0.0003$)

Comment: I think 100 is not enough. Using C code I've tested up to 200k. With 100 with my code my results are like yours.